# Login area for 2 admins

Tags: php, session, passwords

Me and a friend of mine are developing some site and we need custom admin panel where both can log.

```
     $username=array();
            $pass=array();
            $username[0]='user1';
            $username[1]='user2';
            $pass[0]='pass1';
            $pass[1]='pass2';

            if (isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['userName'])) {
if($_POST['password']==$pass[0] && $_POST['userName']==$username[0]
|| $_POST['password']==$pass[1] && $_POST['userName']==$username[1])
                {
                    if (!session_id())
                      session_start();
                      $_SESSION['logon'] = true;
                      $_SESSION['userName'] = $userName;
                      header( 'Location: admin.php' );
                      die();
                }
            }
```

I'm sure there's some better way for logging for 2 persons and is this code secure and good enough for admin login? I don't want to put 4 variables in a database so is it good idea to put these variables in txt file outside the localhost/server and use include? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply store the usernames and passwords in an array like this:

```
$users = array( 'user1' => 'pass1', 'user2' => 'pass2' );
if( array_key_exists( $_POST['userName'], $users ) )
{
   if( $users[$_POST['userName']] == $_POST['password'] )
   {
       // Username and password correct
   }
   else
   {
      // Password incorrect
   }
}
else
{
    // Username incorrect
}
```

However I would store those things in a database.

Comment: Surely this is not going to give the desired result if both post vars are blank?

Comment: Since there is no empty key in the array and no key with an empty value there shouldn't be any problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about security, then you should not put the password in plain text in the source or external file. The better approach will be to hash the password and store in database.

Comment: Thanks. And how to create login for 2 people without using this huge if operator